# Runtime exception in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developing simple android app...its not working when i have open thats app..it will be automatically out from the app.....what is solution?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:557)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "25/{7}/2020"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:362)
    at com.example.agelminutes.MainActivity$clickDatePicker$1.onDateSet(MainActivity.kt:41)
    at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:171)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:172)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Check you date input."25/{7}/2020". Why there are two curly braces?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong date format : `"25/{7}/2020". Check MainActivity.kt line 41